# how to use the img tag

Tags: asp.net

i am a student working in an simple application and i do not know how to use the img tag and i have tryed one such code but while executing the code the image is not showing plz see the code and help me to saw what is the wrong in the code.

**code is:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    &nbsp;
    <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;
        height: 100%;">
        <tr style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
            <td valign="middle" align="center">
                <img alt="" src="C:\Documents and Settings\temp.intern1\My Documents\My Pictures\images4.jpg" />&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 65%; vertical-align: top;">
            <td style="width: 90%;" align="center">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 20px">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100%" style="height: 100%">
                            <div id="Panel1" style="background-color: #87BDEF; height: 300px; width: 600px;">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height: 400px" width="600px">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height: 200px" width="600px">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="right" style="padding-left: 5px; width: 50%;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="USER NAME &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td align="left" style="padding-left: 5px; width: 50%;">
                                                        <br />
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Width="70%"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUserName" ErrorMessage="Please enter Username"
                                                            ControlToValidate="txtUserName" runat="server" Width="70%" ForeColor="red" Style="margin-left: 0px;" />
                                                        &nbsp;
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <br />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <br />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="right" style="width: 50%;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="PASSWORD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td align="left" style="padding-left: 5px; width: 50%;">
                                                        <br />
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="70%"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPassword" ErrorMessage="Please enter Password"
                                                            ControlToValidate="txtPassword" runat="server" Width="70%" ForeColor="red" Style="margin-left: 0px" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                                        <span id="lblInValid" style="color: #C00000; font-family: Verdana; font-size: Small;">
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                                        <table width="50%">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" style="padding-left: 5px; width: 50%;">
                                                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                                                                    <br />
                                                                    <br />
                                                                    <br />
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td align="left" style="padding-left: 5px; width: 50%;">
                                                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="CLEAR" />
                                                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <br />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <br />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="180px">
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

plz some one help me on this code...,

Comment: Your images should be located in your project in an img folder. It's not good coding to get images from an absolute location on your disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an address to an image on your computer, so that will only work when you view the page from that specific computer.

You should copy the image into the web application, for example into a folder named `images`, then you use that address in the image tag:

```
<img alt="" src="images/images4.jpg" />
```

Comment: This should probably be `/images/images4.jpg` as you don't know in which folder in the project his page is located

Comment: @ToonCasteele: Maybe, maybe not. If the application is in a virtual folder, that would make it look for the image in the root application instead.

Comment: That's true, but I think there's a slim chance in this case :)

Answer (score 3):

Your image should be in the folder accessible to your web server. Try including your image into your solution file (assuming you are using Visual Studio), and use relative path, such as "/images/image4.jpg"

Go to some web site (like www.cnn.com), view source for any page and see how they set path to img tags.

You can also use ASP.Net image tag, check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.aspx) for examples and usage.